# PowerShell is slow when i want to run a simple script via keyboard command/shortcut. Any way to let it run faster?

Tags: windows, powershell, command, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I don't have keys on my keyboard to adjust the brightness of my screen. So i made a simple script to increase or decrease the brightness by 10%:

Brightness up:
$Brigthness = Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightness | select -ExpandProperty CurrentBrightness
$Brigthness = $Brigthness + 10
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,$Brigthness)

For reducing the brightness i replace the + by a -.

I saved these scripts as ps1 files and made a shortcut on my desktop to open these in powershell via a keyboard command: Ctrl Shift + for increasing and Ctrl Shift - for decreasing the brightness.

Now here's the problem: when i press the command on my keyboard it takes a while for powershell to start up and run the script. It takes about 5 seconds for my screen to actually change brightness.

Is there any way to adjust the script or something to let it run faster? Just like it would on a normal keyboard shortcut. Then it's almost instant.

I was thinking about already letting powershell run in the background so that it doensn't have to boot up first, but i have no idea how.

Thanks in advance! Really curious if there's a way.

What i did so far:
$Brigthness = Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightness | select -ExpandProperty CurrentBrightness
$Brigthness = $Brigthness + 10
(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,$Brigthness)

Saved this as ps1 in my documents file.

Made a shortcut on desktop linking to the file path and assigned Ctrl Shift + as a keyboard shortcut to run it in PowerShell.

Comment: Please consider placing your code in Markdown code blocks in your question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

- The startup cost of Windows PowerShell's CLI, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), is significant.
- Even if you implement a custom PowerShell command server that keeps running and receives commands to execute through some IPC mechanism, you'll need *some* executable (and therefore launching of a *new process*) that the shortcut file invokes, which must request the execution of the desired command from the command server.

---

Therefore:

- Using a shortcut-key mechanism that relies on shortcut files (`*.lnk`) is *invariably* slow (though with an executable that has a low startup cost it may be fast enough, depending on the use case).
- Consider the following alternatives:

  - Use a dedicated scripting language such as [AutoHotkey (AHK)](http://www.autohotkey.com/), which offers fast, in-process shortcut-key commands based on a resident process.

    - For instance, here are two AHK scripts that may work for you: [one based on WMI](https://gist.github.com/krrr/3c3f1747480189dbb71f), and [one based on calling the Windows API](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/83100-laptop-screen-brightness/)
  - Use a dedicated utility for adjusting monitor brightness that also supports shortcut keys (hotkeys):

    - For instance, [Twinkle Tray](https://github.com/xanderfrangos/twinkle-tray).

Comment: Thanks!! Wil try it out tomorrow on my PC. And hotkeys is the word I was looking for haha! Will let you know what worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use PowerShell you need to keep a script running continuously (or at least the console for you to enter commands).

If you don't like to have a console up and running all the time, you have to revert to some heavier methods involving running the script hidden and triggering on Windows key events or building a Systray tool with a menu...

It's quite possible, but involves a lot more coding then you might be prepared to do.